# How to disable Caching for certain roles in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-2, role-based

I want to enable caching for all Anonymous users of my site.  But for logged in users of certain roles, I want to disable caching. I am using .net4/ASP.Net MVC2.  How do I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... To answer my own question..  The short answer is no. There is no built in way to do this.  But you can emulate this by dynamically adding a unique time stamp query string viz., ts=1234567890 to urls, for the logged in users you do not want to use caching.